# Set html page padding in android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I'd like to set top padding in a html source using JS function.The point is to not reload the page when this function will take effect, that's why I supposed to use `innerHTML` property.

My actual source is:

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      @Override
     public void onPageFinished(WebView web, String url) {
     web.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.style.paddingTop = 100px");
   }
     });
```

this solution is not working, giving me warning:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to write

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      @Override
     public void onPageFinished(WebView web, String url) {
     web.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){ document.body.style.paddingTop = '100px'})();");
   }
     });
```